# What is the closest noun for "that which confirms"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I thought maybe confirmer or confirmator would work, but confirmer is not an english word and the "ator" suffix only applies to words ending in "ate" [(source)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ator). The closest noun I can think of is "validator", which is a synonym of confirm. However I was hoping there was a noun form of confirm itself.

For example, "the confirmator was broken, and clients were unable to establish the requests were submitted".

Comment: 'Clincher' (A fact, argument, or event that settles a matter conclusively): [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/clincher) certainly fits well with the title question. It's rather informal.  But don't you just want 'guarantee' or a synonym for your example sentence? Or is it 'validating mechanism'?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of validating mechanism.

Comment: Looking at the example sentence, perhaps "The automatic acknowledgement was broken, ..."

Comment: @JustinRaymond How about "validator" then? It's already used to describe various kinds of syntax checkers.

Comment: Or you could use *authenticator*, because what you are doing sounds very much like authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the answer not ***confirmation***. It is certainly "that which confirms".

It also works with your example sentence: *The **confirmation** was broken, and clients were unable to establish the requests were submitted.*

Comment: It just occurred to me that with one letter change "confirmation" can turn into "confirmatron", which is obviously a machine that confirms :)

Answer (score 1):

[Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/confirm.html) has

> **confirmator**
>   One who, or that which, confirms; a confirmer.

and

> **confirmer**
>   One who confirms something

along with lots of others, like

> **confirmee**
>   A person who is confirmed via religious rite.

and

> **confirmand**
>   A candidate for confirmation or affirmation of baptism.